# How to get my account un-banned after apologizing for my bad posts

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

This post might be in the wrong section, but this was the only place I could ask.

I read the answer on how to get my posting privileges back after getting banned for posting questions that didn't follow the rules or were received negatively by the community, but even though I have looked at those posts and edited them to fix any mistakes I made, I still have not gained those privileges back.

What should I do?

Comment: Please read the FAQs and every other resource this website has for potentially getting your account re-instated. Asking questions like this doesn't bode well, however...

Comment: How long has it been since you edited your posts?  Did you give them time for the community to actually read them and upvote them?  I don't think editing alone is enough. It might be helpful if you post a link to your questions and ask for help. As it stands right now, there isn't much we can do to help without more information.

Comment: When we say improve your posts, we mean that you should _actually improve_ them. Adding an [apology at the end](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11463413/revisions), without doing anything else, actually makes them worse...

Comment: Its been more than a month. I have been trying to apologize to people on stackoverflow, but people usually either don't reply (maybe don't see me), or they don't see my posts that I have edited and apologized in.

Comment: Don't edit your posts just to apologize, edit your posts to _fix_ them.

Comment: For some of my posts, I did re-iterate my question, in a better format that is asked for by the community. But people either don't read it, or if they do, then they ignore it. :(

Comment: And there you have it.  Fix the post, don't apologize, just fix it. The resources linked above don't mention a requirement to beg for forgiveness, but to instead fix the problems with the posts. Try editing them so that they include information needed to make them great. :) Also, if you can't include links to your questions, there isn't much we can do to help.

Comment: ^ I have fixed some of my questions, except the community either doesn't see those posts or choose to ignore it :(

Comment: Why do we only see 1 question from you? Did you delete the others? If so, deleting content will contribute to a question ban.

Comment: btw: EDIT: I realize this was a really bad post and almost completely broke the rules. I apologize for this post. is better off as a comment, then in the actual question

Comment: @jmort253, No, because this is not the account I generally use. My main account is http://stackoverflow.com/users/1079641/user1079641. I had to login using yahoo to this site because I wasn't able to login through my normal email, as it kept saying "Third Party Cookies have been disabled." Anyways, that's a different issue.

Comment: @saurabhverma Again with the [apologizing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10269410/revisions). Please stop doing that, it _won't_ help lift your ban.

Comment: @saurabhverma - 0_0 So, you admit to sock-puppeting? That usually results in an IP-wide ban.

Answer (score 1):

looking at your question, you should actually post the code as supposed to providing links. shift+enter or 4 (might be 5) will enable formatting.

if you didn't look at this, then look at it, it will tell you EVERYTHING:
[What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

In fact, there are no other answers besides what is in that very link.